# Custom syntax highlighting for VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, plugins, syntax-highlighting

I've been using [John Lam's Vibrant Ink](http://www.iunknown.com/2007/06/vibrant_ink_vis.html) VS color scheme lately and wanted to tweak it so it highlights the method names for a class with a different color. Turns out there is no option in VS for that.

Resharper has [a feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Syntax_Highlighting) that provides custom syntax highlighting. I was wondering how hard is it to write a little plugin that gives you granular custom syntax highlighting? Are there any open source ad-ins like that out there?

**EDIT**

Thanks all, I managed to hack stuff up using DXCore and my VS is looking oh so similar to textmate.

[VS is looking fantastic http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/637/awesomevsgq1.png](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/637/awesomevsgq1.png)

** NOTE **

I had to slightly modify the snippet by Rory so it works with dotted method names and equality operators in C#.

I am now using:

```
            string name = ea.LanguageElement.Name.Split('.').Last();

            if (name == ("op_Equality")) {
                name = "==";
            } else if (name == "op_Inequality") {
                name = "!=";
            }

            ea.PaintArgs.OverlayText(name, 
                ea.LanguageElement.NameRange.Start, 
                Color.FromArgb(255,204,0));
```

Comment: i think that in VS its called by ad-ins

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well as Brian has already said... [My PaintIt plugin](http://www.rorybecker.co.uk/PaintIt.html) will give you some idea as to what can be done with the [DXCore](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/DXCore/).

Also there are some other "Decorative plugins" on our "[Community Plugin Site](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/)" and we have a decent community over in the

[DevExpress IDE Tools](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/default.aspx?GroupID=18) forums if you have any specific questions.

[DXCore](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/DXCore/) is the framework on which [RefactorPro](http://devexpress.com/refactor) and [CodeRush](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) are built which should give you an idea of what sort

of graphical capability they are capable of.

That said you do not need either of these tools to use the [DXCore](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/DXCore/).

**Everything on the [Community Site is "Open Source"](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/) (So is [PaintIt](http://www.rorybecker.co.uk/PaintIt.html))**

To give you an idea of how simple things are... the following code is all you need to add to a basic plugin template get the basics up and running using [DXCore](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/DXCore/)...

```
Private Sub PlugIn_EditorPaintLanguageElement(ByVal ea As DevExpress.CodeRush.Core.EditorPaintLanguageElementEventArgs) Handles Me.EditorPaintLanguageElement
    If ea.LanguageElement.ElementType = LanguageElementType.Method Then
        ea.PaintArgs.OverlayText(ea.LanguageElement.Name, _
                                 ea.LanguageElement.NameRange.Start, _
                                 Color.HotPink)
    End If
End Sub
```

I have created a plugin (called CR_ColorizeMemberNames) based on this code and added it to the [Community Plugin Site](http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/).

The binary is available from my site [here](http://www.rorybecker.me.uk/DevExpress/Plugins/Community/CR_ColorizeMemberNames).

You need only download and install [DXCore](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/DXCore/) and place the [binary of the plugin](http://www.rorybecker.me.uk/DevExpress/Plugins/Community/CR_ColorizeMemberNames) in the plugins folder (Defaults to C:\Program Files\Developer Express Inc\DXCore for Visual Studio .NET\2.0\Bin\Plugins).. Then start VS and your method names should all be in HotPink (Lovely)

Comment: Rory, I had trouble getting paintit to work, but using your code snippet I did manage to get this all hooked up (see my screen shot) thanks so much

Answer (score 4):

To go beyond the simple keyword coloring, details on the Visual Studio Syntax coloring is [defined here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166778.aspx); and details to [implement here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166173.aspx).

These documents outline how the underlying plumbing is, well, plumbed -- and more importantly, goes into detail on how to wire in your own --

Comment: Those are docs for defining a language service from scratch.
If he did that, he would need to re-implement everything, including intellisence. That would be really expensive.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to roll your own, I'd recommend getting [DXCore from DevExpress](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/DXCore/).  I know you can add your own visual elements into VS2008 using this add in, and I believe it's free as well.  there's a good sized community for assistance with writing your own plugins, and there may even be one already made for you.

I'm a big fan of DevExpress, and I run Refactor! and CodeRush.

Answer (score 2):

Get DXCore, and then start with this plugin: http://www.rorybecker.me.uk/PaintIt.html that should get you started with some code to colorize method names. Rory makes his code available, and I think he is a member here at SO...

Comment: Yeah I'm around :) You can email me Rorybecker@gmail.com or follow me on twitter twitter.com/rorybecker . That code is quite old now, but I am working on updating it at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really answer how hard it is or whether there's any open source, but to get it done, you want to take a looki at Custom Text Markers.  See these two articles for details:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/dr._ex/archive/2004/06/09/152220.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165758.aspx

Comment: Text markers are not a good idea for colorization, because they come with a large amount of overhead. You don't want to have to define a marker for every single token.