# Visual Studio syntax highlighting

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008

Is it possible to get the same level of syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2008, that SQL Server Management Studio has? This is regarding T-SQL.

For example SSMS has separate highlighting options for operands, system functions etc, while Visual Studio 2008 only seems to have one 'keyword' for T-SQL.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this has been left out of VS 2008 - hopefully someone can say otherwise!

Answer (score 1):

See this: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505226/custom-syntax-highlighting-for-vs-2008)

To get a better level of control you will have to write an addin and a parser, both of which are very tricky.

VS 2010 will have MEF and WPF which means that writing addins which change the visuals will be significantly simpler.

If you are looking for a simpler framework to write this kind of stuff in VS 2008 have a look at [DXCore](http://devexpress.com/Downloads/Visual_Studio_Add-in/DXCore/).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but someone did come up with an app that will take your VS color settings and convert them over to ones that will work in SQL Server Management Studio. You can find the post about it [here](http://winterdom.com/weblog/2007/10/31/ColorSchemesInSQL2005ManagementStudio.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I use SQL 2008 and VS 2008 DB Pro edition. And what I often do is writing SQL in SSMS and copy & paste to VS.