# How to write Visual Studio addin for custom text coloring?

Tags: visual-studio

I need to write a visual studio 2005+ addin for custom coloring of some file format (for example, i need to highlight all words "test" in files that has ".test" extension). Is it any good tutorials available? MSDN help is very general and huge :(. Preferable language is C#, but VB or C++ will do too :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question might help:

[Custom syntax highlighting for VS 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505226/custom-syntax-highlighting-for-vs-2008)

They talk about building on top of DxCore, which is the base that [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) is built on.

Comment: What's even better is the fact that DXCore is free.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [write a language service](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/VSLanguageService.aspx), which is part of [VSX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsx/default.aspx) (Visual Studio Extensibility)